# ExpandProperty on Select Object throwing errors

Tags: powershell

I am trying to resolve the hostnames from a list of DNS names.
For this I am using the below extract.

```
$Hostname = foreach($Server in (Get-Content -Path "E:\PLM\tc_deploy.net\template\OnePLM_PROD_Servers.txt")) {Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type A}
$Resolved = $Hostname| Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameHost
Write-Host $Resolved
#Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Resolved -Force
```

Problems is (I think because there are no properties to expand for NameHost), I am getting a lot of errors thrown.

Select-Object : Property "NameHost" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:25

- $Resolved = $hostname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameHost
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A:PSObject) [Select-Object], PS
    ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

At the end though, I do get an array with just the host names.
If I do not use the ExpandProperty, I get the result (for each entry in the list): @{NameHost=blabla.#######.COM}, which is not suitable for the Restart-Computer function because it includes the property names.

So basically the ExpandProperty is working, but how do I get rid of the errors?

Br.
Ronald

Tried with and without ExpandProperty.
Expecting an array of hostnames for usage in Restart-Computer function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled with the fact you assign a foreach loop to a variable. By the way the useful property is **Name** and not **NameHost**

I assume following should fulfill your need :

```
foreach($Server in (Get-Content -Path "E:\PLM\tc_deploy.net\template\OnePLM_PROD_Servers.txt"))
{   $Resolved = Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type A | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    Write-Host $Resolved
    #Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Resolved -Force
}
```

Comment: Hi Civette


Thank you for your quick reply. I tried your solution, but the Write-Host $Resolved now gives as a result the following format for all servers in my input list.
TC-P-VIS-001.#########.COM C######2.#########.COM
So the array now includes the DNS name from the input as well (which is not needed.

Comment: Well.... this is the very purpose of "Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type A"

Comment: @Civette `$variable = foreach(...){...}` is a fairly common pattern, very useful for "collecting" all the output from a loop

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
For some strange reason, when I tried to run the Restart procedure with the DNS Alias names, it didn't work. I got error messages that the listed aliases couldn't be found.

With the solution Civette provided, I got different error messages, saying that the requested host was already starting. Which told me that now the DNS alias was accepted.
Therefor I do not need to resolve them anymore and I can use them directly for the restart.

Thanks all for your input.
Ronald.